# Listening to a RTP Stream only if a stream is incoming in C#

Tags: c#, gstreamer, rtp

I`m working on a project to send and receive streams via GStreamer. I want to listen to a certain stream only if it is available, meaning an RTP stream is incoming, otherwise the application is doing something else.
What is the go-to solution for this problem either in the C# application itself or using GStreamer?

My solution would be listening to a certain port and look if its active, but im not sure if this is the right idea

Comment: _"only if it is available"_ - what exactly does that mean (to you)?

Comment: Please expand your description a little of what you want to achive in detail.